Error Message when I try to do command sudo apt update'
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. I have tried to do the command sudo apt update and I get the following error message:
Err:17 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu noble Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Get:18 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main all Packages [9,152 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 0AB215679C571D1C8325275B9BDB3D89CE49EC21 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
What does this mean? And what do I need to do to fix it? I'm still relatively new to Linux and am still learning how to use it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.
